# Record is not loaded in to DataTable using Servelt Jsp Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsp, servlet-3.0

Record is not loaded in to DataTable using Servelt Jsp Ajax i am a beginner of ajax and servlet .when the page is load all the data should display on the Datatable but not displayed. i am tring this since yesterday still didn't solve the problem. what i tried so far i attached below. i really i don't what was the problem it is.

**Datatable**

```
<table id="tbl-category" class="table table-bordered" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th></th>
                                <th></th>

                                <th></th>
                                <th></th>
                            </tr>   
                        </thead>  
                    </table>
```

**jQuery**

```
  function getall()
            { 
                $('#tbl-category').dataTable().fnDestroy();
                $.ajax({
                    url: "view",
                    type : "GET",
                    dataType : "JSON",
                    success:function(data)
                    {
                       $('#tbl-category').dataTable({
                           "aaData":data,
                           "scrollX": true,
                           "aoColumns":
                                   [
                                    {"sTitle": "firstname","mData": "firstname"},
                                    {"sTitle": "lastname","mData": "lastname"} ,

                                    {
                                        "sTitle": 
                                        "Edit",
                                        "mData": "id",
                                        "render" : function(mData,type,row,meta)
                                        {
                                            return '<button class="btn btn-success" onclick="get_details('+ mData +')">Edit</button>';
                                        }
                                   },

                               {
                                        "sTitle": 
                                        "Delete",
                                        "mData": "id",
                                        "render" : function(mData,type,row,meta)
                                        {
                                            return '<button class="btn btn-danger" onclick="get_delete('+ mData +')">Delete</button>';
                                        }
                                   },

                                   ]




                       }); 

                    }   

                });


            }
```

**view Page**

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException 
{

   Connection con;
   PreparedStatement pst;
   ResultSet rs;

       try {
           Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
           con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/details","root","");
            List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

           String query = "select * from record";
           Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
           rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);

           while (rs.next()) {
               String id = rs.getString("id");
               String firstname = rs.getString("firstname");
               String lastname = rs.getString("lastname");

                list.add(id);
                list.add(firstname);
                list.add(lastname);
                String json = new Gson().toJson(list);

                response.setContentType("application/json");
                response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
                response.getWriter().write(json);

           }
```

Comment: can u show your Ajax URL?

Comment: when i run this the url sir  http://localhost:8084/banknd/

Comment: servelt record how to pass through json format sir to index.jsp page

Comment: Not maybe can u check servlet ```response.setContentType("text/plain;charset=UTF-8");``` I think ajax  is confused but you can check

Comment: i editeddd again now check